# IF statement condition within a Azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure

EDIT

I have got a pipeline below and would want it to run an inline script based on the time of the day.

The question should have been around pipelines rather than ARM template.

```
schedules:
- cron: "0 10 * * *"
displayName: Test 1
branches:
include:
- master
always: true

- cron: "0 21 * * *"
displayName: Test 2
branches:
include:
- master
always: true


steps:
- ${{ if eq(schedules.cron, '0 10 ***') }}:
- task: AzureCLI@2
name: RunProcess
displayName: Run test 1
inputs:
azureSubscription: serviceConnection
scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
scriptType: bash
failOnStandardError: true
inlineScript: |

echo 'starting process 1'
```

The way I was able to do this can be found below.

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@02
  name: taskname
  displayName: task display name
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(subnamee)
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    failOnStandardError: true
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $h = (Get-Date).hour
      if ($h -eq 10)
      {
      echo 'command 1'
      }
      if ($h -eq 21)
      {
      echo 'command 2'
      }
```

Comment: If you have a piece of logic that has _2 tasks, one starts a process the second one stops a process_ it seems like an ARM template might not the way to go? Have a look at Logic Apps or Functions. Also, have a look at [Logical functions for ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-logical?tabs=json#if)

Comment: Are you sure is about the Azure ARM Template? I think it's about DevOps.

Comment: Agreed thls is not an arm templat- those are in json format. In order to help you we need to know what tool you are using.

Comment: Apologies all. I have changed the question title and answered the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by changing the script type to PS.

The way I was able to do this can be found below.

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@02
  name: taskname
  displayName: task display name
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(subnamee)
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    failOnStandardError: true
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $h = (Get-Date).hour
      if ($h -eq 10)
      {
      echo 'command 1'
      }
      if ($h -eq 21)
      {
      echo 'command 2'
      }
```